# Encoding two numbers in a 4-bit binary string

Tags: python, algorithm, operation

For example, I have two numbers ranging from 0 to 15. And I wonder if there is any way to encode these two numbers in just 4-bit binary string (or possibly 5-bit)? It is known that 4 bits are needed to represent any single number from 0 to 15, but maybe you could think of your own operation on binary strings, and then recover the input numbers back from the result. For example, if I add `0010 + 1011` as standard, I get`1101`. But with the result of adding it is impossible to predict the components of the sum completely and unambiguously. Cases would have to be considered. But maybe some other own defined action? Was anyone wondering about something like that?

I know that the above question may not meet some portal conditions, but treat this question purely abstractly :)

Comment: are you looking for [`bin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin)?

Comment: There are 2^7 possibilities and you want to represent all of them in 2^4 states?

Comment: I am not talking about the conversion to a binary sequence, but about the possibility of, for example, reading from one 4-bit binary sequence, two input 4-bit binary strings.

Comment: 2^4 < 16 + 16, it's impossible to fit the information into 4 bits. 2^5 bits have the required range, you just need to decide on the right encoding.

Comment: Use a predefined mapping. Then you can define 16 different pairs of numbers, each one in the range of `(0..15,0..15)`. For reasons mentioned above, you cannot encode all *possible* ranges. What you ask is quite like "I can write on one side of a page and on the other. Is there a third side?"

Comment: I understand that there is a range. that's why I was thinking about introducing some of my own operations on strings that would encode two strings into one, and then the input strings could be read from the result of this action. but this is just my theoretical consideration;)

Comment: @deceze how to represent two 4-bit binary numbers by just 5 bit? for example (0101 and 1100), considering there are 16*16/2 unique pairs?

Comment: @Pham Yeah, I can't tell you that either. Just mathematically 16 + 16 = 32 = 2^5. I might be brainfarting on this one though.

Comment: @Pham Trung as a result of the sum of 0101 + 1100 = 10001. And I was thinking about some retrograde reasoning. for example, if as a result of adding (10001) the first two digits are 1 and 0, it means that I had to add two ones to each other. but unfortunately it is not known whether it is 1 + 0 + 1, or 1 + 1 + 0, or 1 + 1 (in the writing of the first left column of addition in a written manner). But maybe it would be possible to think of an action from which such inference would be unambiguous.

Comment: Are you working with numbers? "_4-bit binary **string**_": I suppose you meant representation, otherwise if it's string, then, it will occupy a multiple of 8 bits. Check [\[Wikipedia\]: Pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), but it won't meet your constraints. Unless you don't eliminate some of the cases, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @CristiFati Interestingly, I did not know this function. At the beginning I have ordinary natural numbers, only later I represent them as binary strings. in addition, I do not have all the possibilities. so it's possible that it can help me, but at first glance, the result of the pairing of two numbers is quite large, I have to examine it carefully :)

Comment: If you have a clear list of values that each of the 2 numbers could have, please share it. I assume you want to be able to get the numbers back (otherwise the question would be pointless :) ), is their order important? meaning do you care which is which (there could be a bit saved there too :) )

Comment: @CristiFati my pairing pair:`[0,8], [0,1], [0,10], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [1,9], [2,10], [0,10], [4,12], [2,12], [4,11], [0,11], [6,13], [13,3], [6,14], [14,3], [9,15], [15,11], [15,5], [3,17]`. Where the order does not matter :) And I'm mainly interested in how many bits I need to be able to read all the cases. therefore, it may be helpful to use the pairing function.

Comment: Certainly there can be an improvement here. 10 possible values for one, and 13 for the other (both require 4 bits, but don't exhaust all the combinations), you also have a 17 (but that's not important).

Comment: @Thomasz: So there are 21 possible pairs. If you did nothing wrong, and there is no duplicate, you need to represent the number 21 and can from there index your sequence of pairs, but of course only this specific sequence.

Comment: (0, 10) is a duplicate.

Comment: `Was anyone wondering about something like that?` Con artists. Jules Gilbert.

Comment: Those are the only possibilities? You could hardcode them in a map. But no matter how many bits would occupy, the result will still be an int (32bit, even if tonly the last 5 of them will be used). Did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need at least 8 bits to encode two numbers from 0 to 15. This is because you have (2^4)*(2^4) = 2^8 possible inputs (or 2^7 if order does not matter), and by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) any encoding you use that is less than 8 (or 7) bits will result in a collision, making it impossible to reconstruct your inputs in all cases.

To encode two 4-bit numbers into 8-bits just concatenate them:

```
def encode(x,y):
    return (x << 4) + y
```

And to decode just read the appropriate bits:

```
def decode(z):
    return z >> 4, z & 0xF
```

Demo:

```
>>> encode(11,12)
188
>>> decode(188)
(11, 12)
>>>
```

And if you want to convert to and from a binary string in between you can do:

```
>>> bin(188)
'0b10111100'
>>> int('0b10111100', 2)
188
```

Answer (score 0):

> (...) maybe you could think of your own operation on binary strings, and then recover the input numbers back from the result.

No, that is not possible if you are using the same number of bits for both the operands and the result. See, for example, with 4 bits, like you say, you have 16 possible values, from 0 to 15. If you define a binary operation, assuming it is commutative (otherwise it would be even harder), the number of 2-[combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of those 16 elements (the number of possible pairs of inputs) is 120, and that is without even counting the 16 extra possibilities of using the same input twice. Hence, if you only have 16 possible values in your result, on average every possible result will correspond to between 7 and 8 possible pairs of inputs. No matter what operation you define, you would need at least 7 bits in your result to be able to reconstruct the input.

Another question is whether you can determine the set of *potential* inputs that produced some results. That corresponds to the concepts of [number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) for addition or [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) for multiplication, for example.

Comment: Or, in other words, you are basically trying to encode more than 4 bits within 4 bits, which obviously is not gonna work.